# rails 3.2 and machinist issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-1.9.3, machinist, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've just upgraded to Rails 3.2.1 with Ruby 1.9.3-p0 and I'm using Machinist 2.0. Before updating a large project all my tests passed. The problem I"m having is when I create a blueprint within a 'let' call in my rspec tests and then refer to it in a before do block.

```
  let (:new_post) {Post.make!}

  before do
    Post.stub!(:new).and_return(new_post)
  end
```

This used to work, and now I get the following error:

```
  1) PostsController GET index assigns all posts as @posts
     Failure/Error: let (:new_post) {Post.make!}
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `title=' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/support/blueprints.rb:22:in `block in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is my blueprint:

```
require 'machinist/active_record'
Post.blueprint do
  title {"Post"}
  body {"hello world"}
end
```

For now my work around is to create them using instance variables within the before do block, but it would be nice to use the 'let' calls as it keeps my rspec tests cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny, I just ran across the exact same problem, although I'm on Rails 3.2.1, Machinist 2.0, and ruby 1.9.2-p290. I think there's a conflict between the execution of the `Post.stub(:new)` stub method and the Machinist `make` method, but I haven't dug into the code.

The best solution I've come up with is:

```
  before do
    new_post
    Post.stub!(:new).and_return(new_post)
  end
```

This will initialize the let (since let is lazy-loaded in rspec) before it gets to the stub method. It's hacky, but at least you (and I) can keep the let statement.

Comment: I upgraded to Rails 3.2.1 and had the same issue, but this looks like a good work around for now.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I'll try to look into the code and see which project needs to be notified of the issue.